# Fiddler doesn't detect soap requests from a C# console app

Tags: c#, soap, fiddler

I know that this question has been asked several times here.

I have a simple asp.net web service hosted on the IIS Express (I don't have IIS)
I have a console app with a web service proxy in it that calls some method of the service.
It works fine, but the problem is that it can't be detected by Fiddler.
I tried the following:

setting web.config file and app.config file of both the asp.net and console app using
 DefalutProxy.

I even added a line of code to the console app:

```
GlobalProxySelection.Select = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888);
```

but none of these works and I still can't see the request on Fiddler.

Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: I would suggest using [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) and monitoring the local loopback interface. As far as I know fiddler is not able to do so...

Comment: Are you sure @MarkusSafar ? there are many documents about how to solve this

Comment: No, I'm not sure about this but I can assure you that with WireShark it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the code of the application in question look like? What URL is it using?

The .NET Framework is hardcoded to bypass the proxy server for requests to Localhost or 127.0.0.1. As explained in the answers of the questions "asked several times here", the workaround is to use either `localhost.` (note the trailing dot) or use `localhost.fiddler` as the machine name. The former works even without Fiddler running (but may be rejected by IISExpress) while the latter requires Fiddler to be running but should work fine with IIS Express.

Comment: Tnx @eric for reply. I had even tried that,using localhost., but then the server responded with "bad request"

Comment: Yes, as I said, if you use `localhost.` it's not going to work with IIS Express. Use `localhost.fiddler` instead.